# Checking image type and compression without Image Magick

Tags: php, compression, imagemagick

I'm in a bit of a bind.

I need to write a script that goes through a folder of images (on a server maintained by a different department) and check that they're all uncompressed TIFs. Our local boxes have [*Image Magick*](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) installed, but this server does not. The person in charge of this server is no help (when I requested shell access last week, he replied, "It's a Windows server so...no" as if SSH is platform-dependent) so I need a work-around.

Is there a way to check compression and file type (short of just chopping off the extension) without *Image Magick*?

Comment: TIFF is a container format and provides a vast variation of image encodings. It's not simple to check for compression without examining a bunch of header structures. The values `32773` or `0x8005` indicate run-length encoding for some raster images: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, but you'd need to access something else than ImageMagick or GD. First, make sure that you don't have GD on the server as well, since that too would solve your problems.

Using GD you'd do: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

If the server hasn't got GD either you'd probably need to either use some other web service (and send the image to it) or execute a shell command, using some other image tool installed on the server.

Comment: I just ran gd_info() and it came back blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first X bytes (usually 8) to get the magic number of the file and optionally you can read the header files, looking for TIFs information. Take a look at TIF's file format specifications.

p.s. I will provide you with example if necessary. :)

Comment: How do I read the contents of the files as a string? I've tried file_get_contents, but it doesn't appear to work for this format.

Comment: Excuse me for my later reply :) You will have to use as mentioned fopen/fread/fseek.